# psql: root certificate file "system" does not exist. Why `sslrootcert=system` does not work?

Tags: ssl-certificate, psql

I have two hosts. On both hosts I download and install AWS RDS bundle of certificates. Then I tried to connect to PostgreSQL database:

```
psql "postgresql://user@example.com/user?sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=system"
```

I see that `sslrootcert` option is valid and documented: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-SSLROOTCERT

> When using sslrootcert=system, the default sslmode is changed to verify-full, and any weaker setting will result in an error.

On one host the command works fine, but on the another it returns the next error:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "example.com" (x.y.z.a), port 5432 failed: root certificate file "system" does not exist
Either provide the file or change sslmode to disable server certificate verification.
```

The only different I see is the `psql` version.

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 15.5 (Debian 15.5-1.pgdg120+1)      # The version which works fine
psql (PostgreSQL) 15.5 (Ubuntu 15.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1) # The version with the error
```

Why `sslrootcert=system` does not work?